# Как спрятать ссылку в слово pytelegramapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Как мне спрятать ссылку в слово ?
Ссылка содержится в переменной и достать ни как нельзя.
Пробовал через:

```
linck = random.choice(lincklist)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,* [  какой-нибудь текст ] ( linck ) *)
```

Замечто    *   кавычки
lincklist список с ссылками который другой элемент кода спарсил с сайта.

Comment: Непонятно, что конкретно вы хотите.

Answer (score 1):

```py
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "[какой-нибудь текст](https://google.com)", parse_mode="MarkdownV2")
```

В Вашем случае:

```py
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"[какой-нибудь текст]({linck})", parse_mode="MarkdownV2")
```